# Simple Load-Balancing

Tags: php, symfony, load-balancing, scalability

I have a simple front-end that accepts all incoming requests and serves mostly static content written in PHP. I forward qualified requests from PHP to the backend using curl and serving the responses again to the user.

I have two (the number might increase over time) similar back-ends doing the heavy lifting. I want to add load balancing (random is fine) and health checks.

All these software load balancers seem to be very complex and hard to setup. Is there an easy solution?

I thought about implementing it my self. Should be straight-forward but probably not really battle proof.

Comment: if you want to implement the loadbalancing directly in you application, try gearman. if you want balancing that's transparent to your code, using a reverse proxy would be the way to go, as @skz answered. if you want bandwith-loadbalancing, you will need to edit your DNS records. but whatever you do, be aware: running one app parallelly on several machines is not the easiest of tasks.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks for you comment. Luckily my application is stateless, therefore the parallelism should not be a major problem. Gearman looks interesting but is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably try [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) - an HTTP and reverse proxy server. Should be easy to install and configure.

Comment: Thanks I thought ght NGINX would only support load balancing using NGINX Plux but it seems that it is available for the free version as well. Unfortunately the health checks of NGINX are quite poor. It disables one server for some time if the request fails. The Plus version has better health checks, but is not an option right now.

Comment: Maybe then you should implement a job queue with Gearman (supports foreground jobs) or RabbitMQ (as much as I've tried - only background jobs, but can be done) - both of them smart enough to detect consumer/worker fail and re-queue jobs if everything is done properly to other consumers/workers.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually want to stay away from extra overhead like Gearman or RabbitMQ, even though I'd love to use messaging, I am afraid that this will make my current stack really hard to debug and to develop on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple front-end cloud load-balancer should be sufficient.

Enable the following apache modules :

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_balancer
```

Then, open your `/etc/apache2/conf.d/proxy-balancerconfigure` and configure the modproxybalancer by adding the following lines :

```
BalancerMember http://10.0.0.1  
BalancerMember http://10.0.0.4

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
```

Last, configure your proxy to allow access from all hosts.
Open your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf` and replace the following :

```
Deny from all
```

To

```
Allow from all
```

Restart apache using `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart``

Hope this help you.

Source :
 [How setup a front-end cloud load balancer in apache](https://www.elastichosts.com/blog/add-a-front-end-apache-cloud-load-balancer/)

**EDIT**

For a simple health checker, add this at end of each member :

```
BalancerMember http://10.0.0.4 connectiontimeout=10 retry=600
```

**EDIT2**

For an advanced health checker, see [apache mod_proxy_hcheck](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html) (only available for apache 2.5 and not in the official repository)

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see there is no health check included, right? It just deactivates a BalanceMember for a given time if a user request runs into the timeout. I could not find anything in the docs.

Comment: I've edited my answer, say me if it's not sufficient.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I meant with my comment. When you run into a timeout you just disable that server for a given time. This is not really a health check imho. As I said my back-end is doing some heavy lifting and replies might take up to 30 seconds (in bad, but valid cases). A health check could be pinging the server like every minute on a /health url and checking if 200 is returned. This might introduce time-outs as well, but would avoid re adding the server after a given time without checking if it's available. Or did I understand your solution wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. I see. It seems there is no real health check mechanism (as you explain it) implemented by default for this alternative. see http://serverfault.com/a/632434/313337. Maybe nginx could be a better solution for this (I don't know load balancing with it).
I'll try to find an easy-to-use solution for apache and come back

Comment: This https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html seems to corresponds with your need. You can specify the expected codes for success and fail, timeout, number of checks before disable worker, ...

Comment: The mod_proxy_hcheck is exactly what I am looking for. Unfortunately this is only available for apache 2.5. I have to think about it, since 2.5 is not yet in the official repository.

Comment: Sh*t! Maybe this one http://search.cpan.org/~mgregoro/Apache-HealthCheck-0.01/lib/Apache/HealthCheck.pm

Comment: This lib is 10 years old and seems to be not updated and not working for almost anyone that uses it: http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/A/Apache-HealthCheck.html#Apache-HealthCheck-0.01

Comment: Oops, sorry, I will remove it from my answer.
Hopes you find your need without changing your whole current configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I hope so, too. When Aapache 2.5 is released in the repos I will choose your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

nginx is pretty easy to configure for load balancing:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html